# JpaRepository with @Inheritance: how to define a method that returns all objects whose class implements an interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Java JPA with an inheritance model like the following (table per class approach):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Animal {
...
}

@Entity
public class Dog extends Animal implements Pet {
...
}

@Entity
public class Cat extends Animal implements Pet {
...
}

@Entity
public class Sheep extends Animal {
...
}

public interface Pet {}
```

I then have the following repositories defined:

```
@Repository
public interface AnimalRepository<T extends Animal> extends JpaRepository<T, Integer> {
    //Method here that returns all Pet objects???
    //@Query(??????)
    //List<Pet> findAllPets();????
}

@Repository
public interface DogRepository extends AnimalRepository<Dog> {
}

@Repository
public interface CatRepository extends AnimalRepository<Cat> {
}

@Repository
public interface SheepRepository extends AnimalRepository<Sheep> {
}
```

Is it possible to define a method within AnimalRepository that will return all instances of Pets, i.e. Dog and Cat objects, but not Sheep objects. Currently, my approach is to do the following:

```
List<Pet> pets = animalRepository.findAll()
.stream()
.filter(animal -> animal instanceof Pet)
.map(animal -> (Pet) animal)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I can also use findAll() methods for catRepository and dogRepository. This approach works but I'd like a more reusable method that is in the AnimalRepository interface. Is this possible? Or is there a way to construct a PetRepository, or a better way of getting all objects that implement Pet?

I have tried @Query methods but I can't find a way to use instanceof or an equivalent in the query.

Comment: does one of the options provided as part of the answer help resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that filtering animals in java code instead of in the DB can lead to various problems (e.g. imagine you'd want to load only a page of animals).

---

With Hibernate, you could issue a polymorphic query for all entities implementing a certain interface:

```
List<Pet> allPets = entityManager.unwrap(SessionImpl.class).createCriteria(Pet.class).list();
```

However, this query will actually be executed as 2 separated `selects`, so that e.g. ordering/pagination at the DB would not work.

---

With JPA, only Entity classes are accepted as part of query criteria, so that one would need to either:

1.Manage the "category information" (*Pet*) of the different animal classes outside the class hierarchy:

```
List<Class<? extends Animal>> petClasses = List.of(Cat.class, Dog.class);
List<Animal> pets = entityManager.createQuery(
                      "SELECT a FROM Animal a WHERE TYPE(a) in :classes")
                        .setParameter("classes", petClasses).getResultList()
```

2.Or introduce a new `@Entity abstract class Pet extends Animal {}` which `Cat` and `Dog` extend, so that a query `FROM Pet` would become possible:

```
List<Pet> pets = em.createQuery("SELECT p from Pet p").getResultList();
```